# List Item Attachment

Tags: custom-list, attachments

I am using SharePoint 2013 On-premise environment.

When I try to open an attachment of list item , it gives me an error "Connection refused".

Comment: Please elaborate your problem more: what kind of list, screenshot of the issue. What have you tried?

Comment: You can explore sharepoint logs to see full error text. Use https://sharepointlogviewer.codeplex.com/

Comment: @ Jussi Palo - I am using custom list.

In this list, I have created an item and attached few fies which are of different format like .docx, .pdf, .gif , .jpeg , .html etc

After saving the item , when I try to click on these attachments,it is behaving differently for different formats.

for images like .gif, .jpeg and .png, attachment is opening to show its contents.
.html attachments are also getting saved in system.
But when I try to click on .docx / .pdf attachments it is showing connection refused.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your Office Online Server is not property configured, or is having issues.

When you visit a library and click "new document", does it open a new Word document in browser? (I.e. in Office Online Server)

If you know the name of your Office Online Server, you can check the status using:

```
http://yourOfficeOnlineServerName/hosting/discovery
```